# How Configure one to Many Relationship From AspNetUsers Table To ... using Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

​
Hi

I'm Have two Tables

1.AppUser

2.Sale

How to Configure one to Many Relationship in DataContext.cs Class using Fluent API

From AppUser Table Id  to  Sale Table UserID

AppUser Table Class Which Inherit From IdentityUser

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Domain
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }
       
    }
}
```

Sale Table Class

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class Sale
    {
        public int SaleID { get; set; }
        public int SaleAmount { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Thanks.

​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add relations

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }

         public virtual  ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    }
}

    public class Sale
    {
        public int SaleID { get; set; }
        public int SaleAmount { get; set; }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }

    }
```

Since you are using net core 5 you don't need any fluent apis in this case

but if you use another version you can add

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                   .WithMany(p => p.Sales )
                   .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
            });
```

Comment: I agree with your solution, but I would recommend against it. First, `Sale` and `AppUser` are frequently in different `DbContext`s (especially if Identity is scaffolded by Visual Studio or `dotnet`). Identity may not even be in the database or *in the same* database; so it may not even be possible to set one-to-many relationship. You should use Identity APIs, rather than table relationship. Finally, a lot depends whether the application always saves the ID of current user ("self-service") or it could be a different user ("customer service"). In short, *don't do it*